# How to get name of location by coordinates from shapefile? What package to use?

Tags: python-3.x, geocoding, shapefile

My web-users need to know province\region names (administrative divisions) when they select a city, for example on Google Maps.

Unfortunately, Google does not have such info for some countries, for example for Afganistan, Pakistan, Uzbekistan, Tajikistan, etc.

I found [GADM shapefiles](http://www.gadm.org/country) and via QGIS I opened map and saw assigned names and coordinates of provinces\regions (This is the 1st time I work with maps).

I decided to combine Google Maps with data from shapefiles using coordinates from Google Maps in order to get names from GADM. I tried to google and found different python packages and documentations, but I can't find any information\code sketches about how to get location names from shapefiles using latitude and longitude.

Can anyone help me please with appropriate package/code which can resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution, where I can use shapefiles directly, but as a workaround suitable for me is to use GeoDjango, where shapefiles are imported to PostGIS. Anyway my project is Django-based.

For those, who does not use Django framework, can use just its `shapefiles -> PostGis import module`.

Details here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/